# How to add hyperlink to table row <tr>

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table

I am having a table with its table row `<tr>` generating in a loop to form multiple rows.

I want to give separate `<a>` link to each `<tr>`. Since in table we can add only add data to `<td>` only, I am not able to achieve that.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: For a PHP-only fix, just add the link you want for each row to every cell within that row.

Comment: Andrew, how is that a PHP-only fix?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Html:

```
<table>
    <tr href="http://myspace.com">
      <td>MySpace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr href="http://apple.com">
      <td>Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr href="http://google.com">
      <td>Google</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) Library:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can try this here: http://jsbin.com/ikada3

CSS (optional):

```
table tr {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

OR the HTML valid version with `data-href` instead of `href`:

```
<table>
    <tr data-href="http://myspace.com">
      <td>MySpace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-href="http://apple.com">
      <td>Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-href="http://google.com">
      <td>Google</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).data('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
table tr[data-href] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Only problem I have with this is that href isn't technically valid attribute of a table row.

Comment: This solution don't work without javascript and is not accessible for blind people.

Comment: Using `data-href` would fix the issue with invalid attributes.

Comment: I have a problem with `href` and `data-href`: if I select with jquery `$('table tr').first()` then the `href` or `data-href` attributes disappears, so I cannot access them via `.attr('href')` or `data('href')`

Comment: Another problem is that you are breaking the middle click.

Comment: It will affect to SEO or not?

Answer (score 13):

Playing off of @ahmet2016 and keeping it W3C standard.

HTML:

```
<tr data-href='LINK GOES HERE'>
    <td>HappyDays.com</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
*[data-href] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){       
    $('*[data-href]').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).data('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a problem with `href` and `data-href`: if I select with jquery `$('table tr').first()` then the `href` or `data-href` attributes disappears, so I cannot access them via `.attr('href')` or `data('href')`

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way I've found to turn a table row into a link is to use the onclick attribute with window.location.

```
<table>
<tr onclick="window.location='/just/a/link.html'">
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the first response, more information is needed. But if you're just trying to make a table of links, you can just do

```
<tr><td><a href="...">...</a></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying that you want to make each `<tr>` clickable, you can add a `click` event to each `<tr>`, or better yet, add a `.delegate()` handler to the `table` that manages clicks on its `<tr>` elements.

```
$('#myTable').delegate('tr','click',function() {
    alert( 'i was clicked' );
});
```

This code assumes your `table` has the `myTable` ID:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td> cell </td></tr>
    <tr><td> cell </td></tr>
</table>
```

If this isn't what you meant, then please clarify your question, and post the relevant javascript code you're using.

Comment: For those reading this since jQuery 1.7:
"As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method."
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 1):

The premium suggestion would be to add the tags when you generate the table.  If you need to do it after the table is rendered and you want to use javascript you can always add something like

```
var mytable = document.getElementById("theTable")
var myrows = mytable.rows

for(i=0;i < myrows.length;i++)
{
  var oldinner;
  oldinner = myrows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
  myrows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = "<a>" + oldinner + "</a>";
}
```

or if you need to do it to every cell, your can always

```
var mytable = document.getElementById("theTable")
var myrows = mytable.rows

for(i=0;i < myrows.length;i++)
{
  mycells = myrows[i].cells;

  for(a=0;a < mycells.length;a++)
  {
    var oldinner;
    oldinner = mycells[a].innerHTML;
    mycells[a].innerHTML = "<a>" + oldinner + "</a>";
  }
}
```

I hope you find this helpful

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"window.location='".$links[$i]."'\">......";
```

Javascript without jQuery:

```
 x=1;
 .
 .
 for (...) {
   var tr=document.createElement('tr');
   tr.onclick=function() { window.location='page'+(x++)+'.html'}
   tr.style.cursor='pointer';
 .
 }
```

will let the user click on each row
you can use an array to load the pages too:

```
 x=0;
 var pages=["pagea.html","pageb.html"]
 .
 .
 for (...) {
   var tr=document.createElement('tr');
   tr.onclick=function() { window.location=page[x++];}
   tr.style.cursor='pointer';
 .
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr><td><a></a></td></tr>
```

this?

Answer (score 0):

[`jQuery.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the returned anchor to a `td` and then add to `tr` and [jQuery.appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) `table`

```
$('ith anchor element in array').wrap('<td />').wrap('<tr />').appendTo('table#table_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply gen the  with  and  inside as Nicole suggested:

```
<tr><td><a href="url">title of the url</a></td></tr>
```

Or put the url in the tr tag like 
With jQuery included

```
$('tr.clickable').click(function(){
  window.location = $(this).attr("title");
});
```

to bring you to that page on click (basically hacking a tr to work like a  tag (just a thought, never really try it.

Answer (score 0):

add  in

and change display  style to display:block

and add same  size for  like this:

**CSS:**

```
#Table a {
display:block;
}
#Table td {
width:100px;
hright:100px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="Table">
    <tr><td><a onclick="" href="#"> cell </a></td></tr>
    <tr><td> cell </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-href` script to add href in any html elements. It makes html valid since it add only `data-href` attribute to a element.

https://github.com/nathanford/data-href/